# Run JQuery Mobile App in iPhone

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile app. I'm curious how it looks/runs within an iPhone. I do not have an iPhone. I also, do not have a MAC. Are there any downloadable tools that I can use on a Windows 7 machine to see how the app looks within iPhone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to see how your JQM app looks on iPhone you can try [iphonetester.com](http://iphonetester.com).

You can also might be interested in much more advanced web based tool [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com).

And finally if you need more than that (for example attach to iOS Safari instance to debug your mobile app code) than you need real or virtualized OSX and xCode iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in the Windows environment.

But you can use your computer to create a hackinntosh. A hackintosh is simply any non-Apple hardware that has been made—or "hacked"—to run Mac OS X. This could apply to any hardware, whether it's a manufacturer-made or personally-built computer.

Than you can use it to test an iPhone jQM app in the XCode iPhone emulator. Only downside of this method is that you can not use it to deploy final all into Apple app store.

Here's a short tutorial on what is a hackintosh and how you can deploy it on your computer: http://lifehacker.com/5841604/the-always-up+to+date-guide-to-building-a-hackintosh

And here's an youtube "how to" video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEW6d7m5Zc0